# How to sort a 2 dimensional Integer array both ascending order and descending order

Tags: javascript

I am new to java technology i am facing problem with dealing with `2D arrays`.I have tried many logic all are either `column` based or any other criteria. I have a case to solve like this in my project

I have a `a[3][3]` matrix
like

```
9 8 7
4 3 2
0 5 4
```

my criteria is i want matrix

```
0 2 3
4 4 5
7 8 9
```

as well as

```
9 8 7  
5 4 4
3 2 0
```

My Java Code

```
 public class MatrixExample {

     Scanner scan;

     Integer matrix[][];

     int row,column;

 void create() {

     scan=new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Matrix creation");

     System.out.println("\n Enter Rows");

     row=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

     System.out.println("\n Enetr columns");

     column=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

     matrix=new Integer[row][column];

     System.out.println("Enter the data");


     for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<column;j++) {

            matrix[i][j]=scan.nextInt();

        }

    }

}

void display() {

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<column;j++) {

            System.out.print("\t" +matrix[i][j]);

        }



        System.out.println();

    }

}
void sortmatrix() {
     Arrays.sort(matrix, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
                return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
            } });
    System.out.println("After:");
    for(Integer[] row : matrix) {
        Arrays.sort(row);
        for(Integer num : row) {
            System.out.print(num);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
public static void main(String []args){
    MatrixExample h= new MatrixExample();
    h.create();
    h.display();
    h.sortmatrix();
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to write your own comparator for this

Comment: @leeror ya i write my own comparator but it is doing for row wise not in ascending order

Comment: Please suggest me with any code

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you don't have a 2D 3x3 matrix, you have a linear array of 9 values, as you sort across the rows.

To achieve the desired result, input the 9 values, sort them increasingly and output them in two ways:

- as a 3x3 array,
- as a 3x3 array, taking the array elements in reverse order.

Comment: my requirement is taking 9 values from user and make a matrix and display it in ascending or descending order. @Yves Daoust

Comment: Replace the word "output" by "copy".

Answer (score 0):

Some code will help you:

```
  private static void sortmatrix() {
      int[] elements = new int[row*column];
      int count=0;
      //get elements from matrix
       for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++,++count) {
                elements[count]=matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
       //sort them
       Arrays.sort(elements);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
       //set the numbers in the matrix, ordered
       count=0;
       for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++,++count) {
                matrix[i][j]=elements[count];
        }

    }
```

If you want the matrix in descendant order, just create the matrix with:

```
 count=elements.lenght-1;
 for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++,--count) {
           matrix[i][j]=elements[count];
  }
```

Comment: it worked like a charm thanks you saved me man but ascending order is working fine and descending order is not working and   //set the numbers in the matrix, ordered why use for loop there  @David Herrero

Comment: ya worked fine count=elements.length; to count=elements.length-1; working thanks and i have another i want to transpose the matrix ascending one

Comment: If the solution worked plz mark it as answered. And for the transpose the matrix open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are actually trying to sort a 2D array. You are having some other specific criteria. Anyway i will provide you with 2D array sorting in ascending order :

```
    public class ArraySorting {

  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Krishna
 */

        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Enter the no. of  rows: "); //inputting number of rows
            int m=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter the no. of columns: "); //inputting number of columns
            int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            int A[][]=new int[m][n]; //creating a 2D array

            /* Inputting the 2D Array */

            System.out.print("Enter the elements: ");
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {

                    A[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                }
            }        

            /* Printing the original 2D Array */

            System.out.println("The original array:");
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            /* Sorting the 2D Array */

            int t=0;
            for(int x=0;x<m;x++)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                        {
                            if(A[i][j]>A[x][y])
                            {
                                t=A[x][y];
                                A[x][y]=A[i][j];
                                A[i][j]=t;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Printing the sorted 2D Array */

            System.out.println("The Sorted Array:");
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Th output of the above code is as follows :

[image: Output]

There are other ways to sort a 2D array.

Comment: I think  `Arrays.sort` is better in this situation.

Comment: Ya it will be. As he said he was new I just thought of introducing him to the exact logic. Arrays.sort will be more than enough.

Comment: Then @Krishan chandran please reply with some code if you know any other logic

Comment: You can check my answer @javalatest

Comment: I just did this pgm right now.It dint had any error.could u paste the error. Have you imported all the necessary headers? Also try @DavidHerrero's answer.Its another alternative